# How do I determine the time complexity of an algorithm when using built in functions?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, built-in

I am having trouble determining the time complexity of my algorithm on leetcode. I read through various sources including cracking the coding interview, but it hasn't fully clicked yet and I find that I am mostly making educated guesses with an incomplete understanding of what I am doing. Sorry in advance if my understanding is too far off and my question is bad.

## Algorithm

```
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {string}
 */
var reverseWords = function(s) {
    let newArray = [];

    let wordArray = s.split(' ');

    for (let word of wordArray) {
        const reverseWord = word.split('').reverse().join('');
        newArray.push(reverseWord);
    }

    return newArray.join(' ');

};
```

## Time Complexity

My thoughts were to split this algorithm up into the `wordArray`, `for` loop, and the `return`. I am also using `n` for the length of the `s` string.

The `wordArray` is `O(n)` because the split method iterates over the whole string before splitting it into a new array.

The `for` loop itself is `O(o)` because it runs `o` times which is the number of substrings separated by white space in `n`, and therefore will be smaller than `n`. Within this for loop, I am running three built-in methods on each word. I think this is `O(p)` (where `p` is the length of the longest aforementioned substring). The push is a constant `O(1)` since it should take the same amount of time to push each substring.

Finally, the `return` is `O(o)` because it runs as many times as there are substrings, similar to the for loop above.

The total time complexity is: `wordArray`: `O(n)` + `for` loop: `O(o)` * (3 x built-in methods: `O(p)`).

After reducing, I have `O(n)` + `O(o)`* `O(p)` where `n` is the length of the string, `o` is the number of substrings in the string, and `p` is the length of the longest substring. I think each of these can be dominant terms because `p` may equal `n` if there is there is no white space, so `O(o)` * `O(p)` may be significant. In other words, the left and right side of the plus may be larger than the other depending on the size of the substrings.

## Question

How can I be sure if my calculation is correct? Specifically, how can I determine the time complexity of the built-in functions I utilize in my algorithms so that I can form more accurate time complexity calculations?

Comment: Please ask one specific question per question, and you shouldn't ask for tool recommendations. The time complexity is `O(s.length)`. _"How can I be sure if my calculation is correct?"_ You can't be sure. Even experts make mistakes with complex algorithms. _"how can I determine the time complexity of the built-in functions I utilize in my algorithms so that I can form more accurate time complexity calculations?"_ Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) or [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/#sec-intro).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited out my second question asking for tool recommendations.

Comment: Regarding the docs or specs, where does it talk about time complexity? I checked for `string.prototype.split` but I can't find the time complexity in either the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#specifications) or [specs](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-string.prototype.split).

Comment: The language specification does not specify complexity requirements. That is a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was sure the specification contains an upper bound as in other languages. I didn't check it. But the specification contains the algorithms.